# Use 0x api to swap tokens with PHP

Tags: 0x

I'd like to use the 0x api to swap tokens given on certains conditions included in a PHP file.

However, it seems 0x api/ecosystem revolves around JS since it has lots of utilities and needs npm to run.

Is there a workaround or do I need to port my PHP file to JS ?

Answer (score 1):

The [0x swap API](https://0x.org/docs/api#swap) is completely HTTP based, so all you need is a way to send HTTP requests.

I believe PHP has built-in support for [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl), or you could use the built-in HTTP Client of a framework like Symfony or Laravel to perform your requests.

You're right that a lot of 0x, and indeed a lot of Web3 technologies, are built with JS. I might be easier for you in the long run to make the switch now.